# in php, How to detect the server where you work

Tags: php, localhost, server

I am currently working locally on a project that, once I finish my tasks, I have to upload the changes to a server (which is in the cloud).

The problem is that there are certain addresses that I pointed directly and when  uploaded to the server, I have need to change then manually, for example:

Locally
http://localhost/project/user/test1

to

In the cloud
http://ourserver/projectXYZ/user/test1

Is there any way in php, to know the address of the server where you are and, with this, put these dynamic addresses?

Comment: The best solution is to use relative URLs.

Comment: Why do you use the server in the URL in the first place?

Comment: But if you can't, use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to get the current URL.

Comment: dont use hardcoded urls; create a config.inc.php file where you define the url when you're in localhost or when migrated to a server on www. just change $baseURL = "http://localhost"; to $baseURL = "http://ourserver/"; if you're using git don't version the file because the configuration is going to be different on both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to use URIs that are relative to the document root, without the host part, e.g. `/projectXYZ/user/test1`.
That said, sometimes you need to know the hostname (e.g. if you ever do a 30x redirect, RFC 2616 requires the `Location:` header to absolute URI). In cases like this, your best bet is to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, which has the "contents of the `Host:` header from the current request, if there is one", to quote PHP manual. I wouldn't worry too much about the "if there is one" part; since `Host:` header is mandatory in HTTP, it missing would be an extremely rare edge case.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I'm working with the Twitter API, and it asks for a direction for the CallBack if I put it relative, the API is malfunctioning. Anyway, with  a couple of IFs and this, it ran perfect. Thx!